# Increase of spam bots on edits

Tags: feature-request, spam

There has been a massive increase of spam bots on the edit option of posts.

I have seen an average of 3 a day on my review queues and I used to see one a month if that.

This may be an issue to look into further, maybe there is there is something that can be done to reduce this?

Comment: I've noticed the same, a lot of Justin Beiber fans it seems..

Comment: Baby baby baby ooooooooh.. sorry couldn't help myself

Comment: Hehe, is it your spam bot? ;)

Answer (score 2):

These quite harmless yet annoying Spam Bots run a specific pattern, pretty much like the pattern of pickpocketing. When there is a lot of activity due to an upcoming holiday - these trolls also increase their activity. At least this is my experience in other .SE sites.

We'll see if these things won't disappear by them selves in the beginning of next year. If not, we may need to act.

In the mean time, keep those flags warm and reach for the [Marshal Badge](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/badges/74/marshal)!

## Edit

Thanks to you, Hugh, I found they target this URL:s "https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47027/how-to-link-to-a-local-folder-or-document" answers. Different answer each time, unfortunately. So I've protected the question but am not sure if this will make these bots go away. We'll see what happens.

[image]

---

I'm pleased to present

## New information

On this topic. To help combat the increasing amount of spam and purely abusive users, Stack Exchange has developed systems that work on a network level; actively learning from actions that users and moderators take. These systems are designed to operate silently in the background, you don’t need to do anything special in order to make them work, there aren’t any extra buttons to push.

## Upcoming filters for suggested edits

Soon we hope to be rolling out additional checks into our spam check system to deal with an oft-complained situation - a post getting riddled with suggested edits by spammers. We will track how frequently any given post (question or answer) is spammed in a given amount of time. If someone attempts to spam a known target, they're dealt an immediate and harsh penalty in the system.

Note that detecting these won’t clear them from the system - these edits will still be in the system and must be cleared from the review queue. Similar to audits, edits that are identified as spam edits will be clearly marked for reviewers, informing them that the post is most likely junk and the review should take this into configuration.

Comment: Such a salesmen Benny

Comment: Actually, it may have been my run for the Florence hat.

Comment: @HughWood Answer updated

Comment: the new anti-spam measures aren't working for http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47027/how-to-link-to-a-local-folder-or-document. I'm about ready to just delete and repost the question with a different title. Unless there are other suggestions?

Comment: @mattwilkie Unfortunately you're unable to delete the question, since it got answers. I'll see what I can do, hold on.

Comment: @mattwilkie I've deleted it - please feel free to repost your question, and I'll contact the users posting answers. Is that OK with you Matt?

Comment: ok, done: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89104/in-wki-pages-how-to-link-to-a-local-folder-or-document. Thanks for killing the old one. I hope that works. I have a theory: I think the [Long Path Tool non-answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/84290/8873) was a magnet, a targeting laser.

Comment: @mattwilkie I destroyed the user too, since this was the only post and no linked accounts. So you do SharePoint and GIS as a mod! That's interesting. Find any cross discipline gain yet? :-)

Answer (score 1):

The spambots seem to target a particular URL, so I am guessing somebody finds a target edit URL and adds to the list of sites to be a damn nuisance on.

Locking the post in question seems to have stopped it in the two cases where I tried this, although it could just be coincidence.